# Thevenin's equivalent

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, norton

[image]

Rth = (10+10)||5+16=20 ohms.
I think the Thevenin's equivalent voltage is across the 5 ohms resistor which was found to be 11.2 volts Applying nodal analysis but the answer is supposed to be -16.4 volts.
Can you help me find Eth(Thevenin's equivalent voltage)?

Comment: It asked for the thevenin equivalent at the A-B junction. So why you were trying to work out the voltage across the 5 ohm resistor is beyond me. Read the question. Also, we don't do your homework for you. Explain what you have tried, show us your work and explain where you get confused

Comment: One way is to use superposition.  Open the current source and calculate the a-b voltage.  Next, short the voltage source (put the current source back) and calculate the a-b voltage. Then sum the results.

Comment: Nodal analysis solves this efficiently.

Comment: Good advice: Using that picture as your 'avatar' may seem fun but will cause you more "real world" hassles than it is worth.

Answer (score 2):

Yes your analysis to find the thevenin resistance is spot on. Regards the voltage and that confusing current source, what I'd do is split that current source so that it takes 3 amps from node a to node b and another current source of 3 amps injects 3 amps into the junction of the two 10 ohm resistors: -

[image]

I do it as a visual aid to help me see things clearer. Your original circuit with the voltage source converted to a 2.4 amp current source in parallel with its 10 ohm resistor is on the left. On the right is the split current source(s) and as you can see, my sim tells us that this idea produces exactly the same results but the circuit on the right is easier to work out.

For instance I can now parallel I3 and I4 like this: -

[image]

Then convert back to a voltage source of 54 volts in series with 10 ohms: -

[image]

Then convert the 54 volts to a current source of 2.7 amps in parallel with 20 ohms: -

[image]

And you can probably see that if I combine the 20 ohm and 5 ohm parallel resistors I get 4 ohms and this adds to the 16 ohms to give you a thevenin resistance of 20 ohms....

.... But I don't see how you can get a thevenin voltage of 11.2 volts so I think you have made a mistake somewhere. Clearly I haven't!

Answer (score 0):

Nodal analysis is a simple, effective approach. you have the correct \$\small R_{TH}=20\Omega\$, but \$\small V_{TH}=-49.2V\$ and the voltage across the \$\small 5\Omega\$ resistor is \$\small -1.2V\$, with ground at terminal 'b'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i'd do it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkNpl9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

1. do a Wye-Delta transform (R2, R3, R4) → (Rx, Ry, Rz)
2. transform Norton source (I1, Rx) to Thevenin source and
   Thevenin source (V1, R1) to Norton source
3. combine the two parallel resistors R1 and Ry and transform back to Thevenin source
4. combine two Thevenin sources to one and transform to Norton source
5. combine parallel resistors and transform back to Thevenin source